# Assigning foreign key to my primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am just a learner when it comes to asp.net and I am currently learning mvc5 as I have vs2013 installed in my system.

The questions I have goes this way:

I want to code a simple application to quicken my learning in asp.net programming. What I'm currently coding that is so problematic to me, as a new asp.net and c# programmer, is I can't add a profile to the apps.

I opened a new asp.net mvc apps and some folder was automatically created for me. Now you will agree with me that, only username, email and password are required of you to register for the new app.  I want to add a profile page to the same database that Microsoft created by default but I don't know how to add it. I created a profile class file in my model folder but I don't even know how to set a foreign key in case I want to use some particular entity from other class...

My code is shown below... please how do I add this to the default database and to assign the key as the foreign key?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebCHECKING.Models
{
    public class Profile
    {
        public int ProfileID { get; set; }

        public string Firstname { get; set; }

        public string Secondname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Phone { get; set; }

        public string Picture { get; set; }

        public string Facebook { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public DateTime Datejoined { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code shows one single entity class with possible PK ProfileID. Which is the entity class you want to refere as a foreign key?

Comment: Don't be annoyed, i'm just learning asp.net. The default database that visual studio builds for you after creating a new web application, how can you create another model to relate with the default database? Please, help me. I have read many books but all are with no help

Answer (score 0):

As opposed to creating a new class to store the profile info you could expand the existing AplicationUser class with these new fields. Check out this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx). The article is actually referenced in your project (open IdentityModels.cs). If you go with this approach you may want to make the additional fields optional so that the user doesn't have to fill everything out as they register.

If you're set on using a seperate class for profile data, add `using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;` to your model and reference the ApplicationUser like: `public virtual ApplicationUser UserPerson {get; set; }`. Check out this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936433/asp-net-mvc-5-identity-application-user-as-foreign-key) for details regarding setting the value of the field in your controller.

-Edit-

Sorry, didn't see your first question about the DB. If you're using Entity Framework, you can add a controller for this model and select the MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework option. This way, EF will add a database context for you and scaffold a bunch of views and controller actions. If you'd rather not scaffold everything like that you can open up IdentityModels.cs and under the `public static ApplicationDbContext Create()` method, add a DbSet statement like `public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WebCHECKING.Models.Profile> Profiles {get; set; }`. You'll have to run a database migration as well to create the tables.

-One more edit-

If you need to reference another class (other than ApplicationUser), simply substitute the data type for the name of the class like: `public profileStuff stuff {get; set; }`. EF will add a column to your database table for that class specifying an Id to the class you're referencing it in. [This](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/introduction-to-asp-net-mvc) series of "getting started" videos might be pretty helpful in this context.

Comment: I will try it then get back to you. Thanks fòr the time

Comment: Just tried it. Your solution solved it by adding my table to the database. Now what i need now is, for example, i have a model for a friend.cs and i want to link such a friend to his profile insuch a way that if you preview the friend list and then click on his name, his profile details will be displayed for you. I understand that it has to do with foreign key between the profile.cs and the friend.cs but please can you help me in writing just a small code and then explaining it to me. The internet just keep confusing me.

Comment: @Switjoseph Sorry for the late reply, I was camping :) Anyways, going off of your comment I'm guessing that the 'friends' in the list correspond to actual profile records? In that case you probably want to create a list of Users to store in your profile.cs class to store the friend list and use the friend.cs class as a view model to display the profile details. You should also make another question on SE if you're still working on this just so anyone who stumbles on this question in the future can understand what's going on